Trying to update database from swift URLSession returns 503
I am updating 2 tables in my database. One works HTTPURLResponse 200. The other fails response 503.
The one that doesn't swift code. All parameter values are set and valid. Showing my POST method but GET also fails with 503 error.
private func post() async throws {
    let rcid = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: DefaultKey.rcID.rawValue) as? String ?? "NOT SET"
    
    guard let url = URL(string: "https://example.com/folder/subfolder/insertUserIntoDBPOST.php") else {
        throw URLError(.badURL)
    }
    
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    
    let parameters = [
        URLQueryItem(name: "Line", value: selectedLine),
        URLQueryItem(name: "Depot", value: selectedDepot),
        URLQueryItem(name: "RCID", value: rcid),
        URLQueryItem(name: "RemainingFreeLaunches", value: String(remainingFreeLaunches)),
        URLQueryItem(name: "SubscriptionStatus", value: subscriptionDuration.rawValue)
    ]
    
    let parameterString = parameters.map { "\($0.name)=\($0.value ?? "")" }.joined(separator: "&")
    request.httpBody = parameterString.data(using: .utf8)
    
    do {
        let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)
        
        guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse else {
            throw URLError(.badServerResponse)
        }
        
        if httpResponse.statusCode == 200 {
            // do something with a successful update
        } else {
            /// throw the error (for eg 503) 
            throw URLError(.badServerResponse)
        }
    } catch {
        throw error
    }
}

The server side PHP
<?php

require_once("../../includes/connection_auth.php");

if ($connection->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $connection->connect_error);
}

if (isset($_POST['Line'], $_POST['Depot'], $_POST['RCID'], $_POST['RemainingFreeLaunches'], $_POST['SubscriptionStatus'])) {
    $line = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['Line']);
    $depot = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['Depot']);
    $rcid = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['RCID']);
    $remainingFreeLaunches = (int) $_POST['RemainingFreeLaunches']; 
    $subscriptionStatus = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['SubscriptionStatus']);
} else {
   die("Missing POST data. Please ensure all required fields are provided.");
}

$insertQuery = "INSERT INTO usersTable (Line, Depot, RCID, RemainingFreeLaunches, SubscriptionStatus) 
                VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) 
                ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
                Line = VALUES(Line), Depot = VALUES(Depot), RemainingFreeLaunches = VALUES(RemainingFreeLaunches), SubscriptionStatus = VALUES(SubscriptionStatus);";

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($connection, $insertQuery);

if ($stmt === false) {
    die("Error preparing query: " . mysqli_error($connection));
}

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sssis", $line, $depot, $rcid,$remainingFreeLaunches, $subscriptionStatus);

if (mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {
    echo "Record inserted/updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . mysqli_stmt_error($stmt);
}

mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
$connection->close();
?>


Stop using mysqli_real_escape_string. Remove it all from your code. Make sure you are using prepared statements everywhere

I shall remove it and see if that helps. I use the prepared statements in the php that returns 503. Is there a reason why removing the mysqli_real_escape_string would be better ?

mysqli_real_escape_string damages your data. You don't need it if you are using prepared statements.

when you get a 503 response from PHP, you need to check the error log for the error message and then act accordingly
